# UpdateSecurityStampAsync in Identity OWIN claims

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

UpdateSecurityStampAsync in UserManager class of AspnetIdentity, is not updating the OWIN IUserClaimsPrincipal.

UpdateSecurityStampAsync

Test to reproduce:

1. Login page using aspnet identity, on login following

> PasswordSignInAsync
>   explicitly make a call to update security stamp 
>   UpdateSecurityStampAsync

Then verify the context.User.Identity - I expected to see updated security stamp. but this seems to be old stil.

How to update Katana cookie claims if we have code like below

```
     await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()
    if (result.Succeeded)
                {
    _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SigninManager has a method update the same.

```
//Refresh the cookie to update securitystamp on authenticationmanager responsegrant to the current request
                    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user)
```

;